# Is it possible to run this command grep with multiple slashes as shell command?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm new to Ansible I'm trying to run this command to verify AIDE is installed by running in Ansible. when I run my playbook I get non-zero return code error. I'm not sure if single quotes or double quotes needed for my playbook to run correctly. Please I need assistance.

```
- name: "Verify AIDE to cryptographic mechanisms are set to protect the integrity of audit tools"
  become: true
  shell: egrep '(\/usr\/sbin\/(audit|au|rsys))' /etc/aide.conf
  register: AIDE_Status
```

I tried to add double quotes between parenthesis of the command returned the same error. Moved quotes between egrep and /etc/aide.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *egrep* works as expected. For example, given the file for testing

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/aide.conf 
\usr\sbin\audit
```

the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: egrep '\usr\sbin\(audit|au|rsys)' /tmp/aide.conf
      register: aide_status
    - debug:
        var: aide_status
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  aide_status:
    changed: true
    cmd:
    - egrep
    - \usr\sbin\(audit|au|rsys)
    - /tmp/aide.conf
    delta: '0:00:00.003672'
    end: '2022-10-26 22:14:13.735346'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2022-10-26 22:14:13.731674'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: \usr\sbin\audit
    stdout_lines:
    - \usr\sbin\audit

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir Botka that worked!! I think it was how the parenthesis and quotes that I was trying to set cause my playbook to error.